# for detects the spaces in the file as multiple lines

Tags: bash, shell-script, for

I am now developing a script to copy some files from directory A to multiple directories B following some directives , the script is working fine , but when it comes to files with spaces on them , he just considers them as multiple files , for example:

`my_super_cool_file_2007039904_11 (3rd copy).pdf`

when the file is in this loop:

```
for i in $(find $parent -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f|cut -c 11-);do
echo "this is the file: $i" 
done
```

it is considered as multiple files :

```
  this is the file: my_super_cool_file_2007039904_11
  this is the file: (3rd 
  this is the file: copy).pdf
```

i've tried replacing the `space` with `\space` using `sed 's/ /\\ /g'`
 but it does not seem to solve my problem, for the loop it's 3 different files, i had also the same problem using `ls`, and i need to stick to use `find`

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: Thank you but i need to stick to use find , there are some constraints.

Comment: You'll find plenty of approaches at that Q&A to use `find` _correctly_ including to address your space problem and why your approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `-maxdepth 1` and `-mindepth 1`, you may as well just do a simple loop (in `bash`):

```
for name in "$parent"/*; do
    if [ -f "$name" ]; then
        dir=${name%/*}  # dir=$( dirname "$name" )
        dir=${dir##*/}  # dir=$( basename "$dir" )
        printf 'The directory is "%s"\n' "$dir"
    fi
done
```

Looping over the result of `find` is generally bad practice: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,and to give you a better idea about the problem , ./A/B/C/myfile.pdf  i need to get the name of thedirectory C and then depending on it's name i'll move the fiel to another location , so  i only need to correct the space problem.

Comment: @Kingofkech The changes I just made will pick out the name of the directory.

Comment: Note that (contrary to `find`) it would not include hidden files and `[ -f "$name" ]` would be the equivalent of GNU `find`'s `-xtype f` (also include symlinks provided they point to regular files).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `cut -c 11-` is intended to remove the directory part of the file path, with GNU `find`:

```
find "$parent" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf \
  'this is the file: %f\n'
```

With any POSIX `find`:

```
find "$parent/." ! -name . -prune -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    file=${file##*/}
    printf "this is the file: %s\n" "$file"
  done' sh {} +
```

More reading at:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,and to give you a better idea about the problem , ./A/B/C/myfile.pdf  i need to get the name of thedirectory C and then depending on it's name i'll move the fiel to another location , so  i only need to correct the space problem , and what does the -prune do ?.

Comment: @Kingofkech `-prune` tells `find` not to descend into that directory. That's the standard approach at implementing GNU `find`'s `-maxdepth`.

Comment: That `C` would be `"$(basename -- "$parent"}"` or `"${parent##*/}"` since you're getting files at depth 1, so it should be a matter of `case $parent in (*/C) find "$parent" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} /some/where \;; esac`, that doesn't explain why you'd want to strip the first 10 bytes of each line of each file path.

Answer (score -1):

Put the $(find $parent -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f|cut -c 11-) in quotes and so:

```
 "$(find $parent -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f|cut -c 11-)"
```

Comment: It did not work , any other suggestion ?

Comment: @Kingofkech "Did not work"? In what specific way did it not work?

Comment: it did not work because it only loops one time, it returns the full loop into the variable in one sigle time , let me explain:  ` for i in "$(find $parent -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f|cut -c 11-)";do`  the variable i will contain al the output : file1 file2 file3 concatenated.