# What is a faster way to extract the year from file names to move them to year based directories than my current approach of using `cut` and `rev`?

Tags: bash, cut

I have a web application that access a remote storage running Linux to get some files, the problem is that the remote storage have currently 3 million files , so accessing the normal way is a bit tricky.

So I needed to work on a script that is going to make it a little bit more easy to use , this script is going to reorganize the files into multiple folders depending on their creation date and specially their names,i made the script and it worked just fine, it intended to do what it meant to do, but it was too slow, 12 hours to perform the work completely `(12:13:48 to be precise)`.

I think that the slowness is coming from the multiple `cut` and `rev` calls I make.

---

**example** :

I get the file names with an `ls` command that I loop into with for, and for each file I get the parent directory and, depending on the parent directory, I can get the correct year:

```
 case "$parent" in
                ( "Type1" )
                year=$(echo "$fichier" | rev | cut -d '_' -f 2 | rev );;

                ( "Type2" )
                year=$(echo "$fichier" | rev | cut -d '_' -f 2 | rev);;

                ( "Type3" )
                year=$(echo "$fichier" | rev | cut -d '_' -f 1 | rev | cut -c 1-4);;

                ( "Type4" )
                year=$(echo "$fichier" | rev | cut -d '_' -f 1 | rev | cut -c 1-4);;

                ( "Type5" )
                year=$(echo "$fichier" | rev | cut -d '_' -f 1 | rev | cut -c 1-4);;
                esac
```

for **type1** of files :

```
the file==>MY_AMAZING_FILE_THAT_IMADEIN_YEAR_TY.pdf
```

I need to get the year so I perform a reverse cut:

`year=$(echo "$file" | rev | cut -d '_' -f 2 | rev );;`

for **type2** of files :

```
the file==>MY_AMAZING_FILE_THAT_IMADE_IN_YEAR_WITH_TY.pdf
```

etc...

and then I can `mv` the file freely : `mv $file /some/path/destination/$year/$parent`

and yet this is the simplest example, there are some files that are much more complex, so to get 1 information I need to do 4 operations, `1 echo , 2rev and 1echo`.

While the script is running I am getting speeds of `50 files/sec to 100 files\s` , I got this info by doing a `wc-l output.txt`  of the script.

---

Is there anything I can do to make it faster? or another way to cut the files name? I know that I can use `sed` or `awk` or string operations but I did not really understand how.

Comment: _Is there anything i can do to make it faster ?_ - Sure, but you don't give enough information for a more useful answer.

Comment: @SatōKatsura   what information i need to add ? i'll give them gladly

Comment: What do the "much more complex" filenames look like? What does the directory structure look like? How does `$file` get its value? What does your current code look like? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @Kingofkech How are you reading the list of files?  How are you renaming them?  Most people have a hard time optimizing code they didn't see, you know.

Comment: i've edited the post now.

Comment: You're doing way too many operations per file, and also getting the list of files with `ls` is not a good idea.  You can probably do everything with a single `find` and Perl `rename`.  But again, you don't give enough information for a full answer.  Good luck.

Comment: i can not use find , because using find to loop over file names is really bad , you can ask @Kusalananda he is the one who recommended it in another question.

Comment: @Kingofkech You can do it with `find`, no problem. Are the years the only four-digit number in the filenames?

Comment: find detects files with spaces as multiple lines , i've already asked this questions and you've answered it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396000/for-detects-the-spaces-in-the-file-as-multiple-lines)

Comment: @Kingofkech That's because you probably parse the output of `find`. I'm currently updating my answer. Are the years the only four-digit number in the filenames?

Comment: Real example of the files

`Type 1:
FA_ERDXSER_CALSE_RASM_2017047361_YEAR_20170922.pdf  `


`Type 2:
FILE_SENT_PAID_1998027890_YEARMMdd.pdf"  `

Comment: @Kingofkech `YEARMMdd`? Is that the _actual_ filename?

Comment: YEAR=Year and the MM is the month and the dd is the day for example 20170223 is the 23 of February 2017, and i need to get the YEAR in orded to move the file

Comment: Please explain what you want to do instead of what you are doing. As you point out, your approach is really not optimal. First because you're using `ls` which means it will break on weird file names and then because this seems way too complicated. We can't really help you though since you don't clearly explain what you are trying to do with these files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the `YEAR` portion of the filename `MY_AMAZING_FILE_THAT_IMADEIN_YEAR_TY.pdf` without using external utilities:

```
name='MY_AMAZING_FILE_THAT_IMADEIN_YEAR_TY.pdf'

year=${name%_*}    # remove everything after the last '_'
year=${year##*_}   # remove everything up to the last (remaining) '_'
```

---

After update to the question:

Moving PDF files from under `topdir` to a directory `/some/path/destination/<year>/<parent>` where `<year>` is the year found in the filename of the file, and `<parent>` is the basename of the original directory that the file was found in:

```
find topdir -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec bash ./movefiles.sh {} +
```

`movefiles.sh` is a shell script in the current directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

destdir='/some/path/destination'

for name; do
    # get basename of directory
    parent=${name%/*}
    parent=${parent##*/}

    # get the year from the filename:
    #  - Pattern:  _YYYY_         (in the middle somewhere)
    #  - Pattern:  _YYYYMMDD.pdf  (at end)
    if [[ "$name" =~ _([0-9]{4})_ ]] ||
       [[ "$name" =~ _([0-9]{4})[0-9]{4}\.pdf$ ]]; then
        year="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    else
        printf 'No year in filename "%s"\n' "$name" >&2
        continue
    fi

    # make destination directory if needed
    # (remove echo when you have tested this at least once)
    if [ ! -d "$destdir/$year/$parent" ]; then
        echo mkdir -p "$destdir/$year/$parent"
    fi

    # move file
    # (remove echo when you have tested this at least once)
    echo mv "$name" "$destdir/$year/$parent"
done
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer but are those instructions going to make my code faster then the state he is in right now ? (compared to the cut and double rev)

Comment: @Kingofkech Yes, but it also depends on the context of your code. How does `$file` get its value, for example? Update your question to give a bit more context to what it is you're doing.

Comment: i've edited the post now

Comment: @Kingofkech See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much i think that this is much more optimal , i did not really thought of using find to call a script , that will be more optimal.

Answer (score 2):

You may apply **sed** approach to extract *year* value:

```
year=$(sed -E 's/.*_([0-9]{4})_TY\.pdf/\1/' <<<"$file")
```